# Opening a Document Picker for local iphone files in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickervc

I know that a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` can be used to select a file from the iCloud but I want to display the user a list of documents present on the iPhone locally and finally extract the URL of the document that the user selects. I have read in a few threads that this can't be achieved directly but clearly apps like WhatsApp and telegram implement these functionalities. Does someone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `UIDocumentPickerViewController`? Have you tried to use it? What is your actual issue?

Comment: Where are these files on the device?  Are they in the picture library?  Inside the documents of the app?  Or just randomly on the device?

Comment: I want to select a picture or a document from the device storage and store its url, so that I can access the file later on. Similar to how I can send a attachment on WhatsApp(in this case, just select it and not send it) and then when i click on the sent file, it opens.